# pyopencl returns wrong float3 values in array

Tags: arrays, opencl, pyopencl

My pyopencl programs are behaving strange and I figured I'm receiving inaccurate values back from the opencl kernel.

Given the following example:

```
import pyopencl as cl
import pyopencl.array as cl_array
import numpy
from pyopencl.elementwise import ElementwiseKernel

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

n = 20

kernel = ElementwiseKernel(ctx,
    "float3 *x",
    "x[i] = (float3)(1,1,1)",
    "assign")

x = numpy.empty(n, dtype=cl_array.vec.float3)
x_gpu = cl_array.to_device(queue, x)

kernel(x_gpu)

print x_gpu.get()
```

I expect it to return an array full of (1, 1, 1)s. However, the output looks like this:

```
[(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) (0.0, 1.0, 1.0) (1.0, 0.0, 1.0) (1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) (0.0, 1.0, 1.0) (1.0, 0.0, 1.0) (1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) (0.0, 1.0, 1.0) (1.0, 0.0, 1.0) (1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) (0.0, 1.0, 1.0) (1.0, 0.0, 1.0) (1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) (0.0, 1.0, 1.0) (1.0, 0.0, 1.0) (1.0, 1.0, 0.0)]
```

or like this

```
[(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) (4.588972210970911e-41, 1.0, 1.0)
 (1.0, 4.203895392974451e-45, 1.0) (1.0, 1.0, 1.3592595103950726e-43)
 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) (0.0, 1.0, 1.0) (1.0, 0.0, 1.0) (1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) (1.401298464324817e-45, 1.0, 1.0)
 (1.0, 2.0795269210580285e-42, 1.0) (1.0, 1.0, 0.0) (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
 (0.0, 1.0, 1.0) (1.0, 0.0, 1.0) (1.0, 1.0, 1.401298464324817e-45)
 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) (4.792440747990874e-43, 1.0, 1.0) (1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
 (1.0, 1.0, 0.0)]
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue with OpenCL, PyOpenCL or I'm doing something terribly wrong.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: i dont know anything about PyOpenCL, but in C `float *x; x[0]=1.0;` is assigning values to memory that you haven't allocated, basically the x points to nothing.

Comment: @GradyPlayer `float3 *x` is the function header for the kernel function in OpenCL and `x[i] = (float3)(1,1,1)` is the function body.

Comment: function header? I know OpenCL in C... not sure what that means.

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice given [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/518759/bug-in-float3-addressing/), I've changed all my code to use `float4` instead of `float3` and all issues have disappeared.

> Indeed, that is very frustrating, however I would discourage the use of any type aligned to 3*sizeof(), because GPUs don't handle it well. If on host side you ask the size of these types, you will get sizeof(cl_float3) = sizeof(cl_float4). So when even host side does not use it properly, it gets very messy, even if device would use it properly.
>
> GPUs are highly optimized for types aligned to either 4 bytes, or 16 bytes. Even if you need only 3 variables in a vector, use float4 and just disregard the last element. If you don't want to waste the memory, use three independant arrays of floats.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official OpenCL specs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_C.html#alignment-of-types) any vector of 3-component elements will be aligned as if each element had 4 components.

> 6.1.5 Alignment of Types
>
> A data item declared to be a data type in memory is always aligned to the size of the data type in bytes. For
>   example, a float4 variable will be aligned to a 16-byte boundary, a
>   char2 variable will be aligned to a 2-byte boundary. For 3-component
>   vector data types, the size of the data type is 4 * sizeof(component).
>   This means that a 3-component vector data type will be aligned to a 4
>   * sizeof(component) boundary.